# Error in LEFT OUTER JOIN with Having,Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this MYSQL QUERY and I tried many ways but got error

The Query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM 
(  
   SELECT SUM(C.fail) AS FAIL_COUNT, A.riskclassifyAS riskclassify,A.logicaldel 
   FROM tc_details AS A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tce_master AS B ON A.tc_name=B.tce_tcname AND A.project=B.project 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN release_details AS C ON  A.tc_name=C.TC_id AND  A.project=C.project  
   GROUP BY A.TC_NAME, A.TC_Desc, A.project, A.tc_priority, A.criticality, B.tce_effectivness 
   HAVING A.project='JupiterQA' AND A.logicaldel=0 AND  
   (
      (criticality <3 OR criticality IS NULL) AND 
      (fail_count>0 OR B.tce_effectivness>0)
   );
```

The Error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Can you tell me the what i'm did wrong in this query.

Comment: This particular error nearly always means 'missing parenthesis'

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just write

```
Select count(distinct A.TC_NAME, A.TC_Desc, 
       A.project, A.tc_priority, 
       A.criticality, B.tce_effectivness ) cnt
From tc_details AS A 
    LEFT JOIN tce_master AS B 
          ON A.tc_name=B.tce_tcname 
               AND A.project=B.project 
    LEFT JOIN release_details AS C 
          ON  A.tc_name=C.TC_id 
               AND  A.project=C.project
Where A.project='JupiterQA' AND A.logicaldel=0 
   AND coalesce(criticality, 0) < 3
   And (count > 0 Or B.tce_effectivness > 0)
```

Since there are no aggregate functions (`Sum(). Min(), Max()`, etc.) in your select clause, the query is nothing more than counting the number of buckets defined by the expressions in the group by.  This is equivalent to a `Count (Distinct )`

... and, since there are no aggregate functions in your having clause, these predicates can be in the Where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an alias name for the subquery and a `)`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM 
(  
   SELECT SUM(C.fail) AS FAIL_COUNT, A.riskclassifyAS riskclassify,A.logicaldel 
   FROM tc_details AS A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tce_master AS B ON A.tc_name=B.tce_tcname AND A.project=B.project 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN release_details AS C ON  A.tc_name=C.TC_id AND  A.project=C.project  
   GROUP BY A.TC_NAME, A.TC_Desc, A.project, A.tc_priority, A.criticality, B.tce_effectivness 
   HAVING A.project='JupiterQA' AND A.logicaldel=0 AND  
   (
      (criticality <3 OR criticality IS NULL) AND 
      (fail_count>0 OR B.tce_effectivness>0)
   )
) tmp
```

Comment: Is the alias compulsory ? I think he is only missing the braces.

Comment: You need the alias name for a subquery.